# UIDocumentPickerViewController not loading document from iCloud on device

Tags: icloud

I just tried to add iOS's document picker (UIDocumentPickerViewController) as directed by the [Document Picker Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/AccessingDocuments/AccessingDocuments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014451-CH2-SW2)

I'm trying to Import (i.e. copy locally...hopefully the simplest case) a file using the iCloud document provider (I've tested others such as DropBox and Google Drive and they work fine).  Here's how I call up the document picker menu:

```
...
UIDocumentMenuViewController *documentPickerMenu = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.text", @"public.data"]
                                                    inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
documentPickerMenu.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:documentPickerMenu animated:YES completion:nil];
...
```

and here is how I bring up the provider-specific document picker:

```
- (void)documentMenu:(UIDocumentMenuViewController *)documentMenu didPickDocumentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)documentPicker
{
    documentPicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and here is my delegate function, which never gets called (i.e. never see log line, breakpoint never hit):

```
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url {
    if (controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerModeImport) {
        NSLog(@"Opened %@", url.path);
    }
}
```

I tested it and it worked fine on the iOS simulator.  However when I load it on an iOS device (an iPad), the document picker comes up fine, shows me valid iCloud documents, but when I pick one all I see in the console is:

```
plugin com.apple.UIKit.fileprovider.default invalidated
```

And my delegate function `UIDocumentPickerDelegate:didPickDocumentAtURL:` function is never called.

I believe I have properly provisioned the application with the iCloud entitlements.

Can someone please help?

Comment: **UPDATE** I've asked some colleagues to try the _exact same app installation_ on their iPad devices with their own iCloud account, and _they_ were able to get it to work.  What could be the difference??

Comment: I'm having the same problem. My delegate is never called. Not on "Done" or if selecting a file. I can see the document is been downloaded but when the dialog is auto-dismissed, nothing happens.

Comment: my delegate function  UIDocumentPickerDelegate:didPickDocumentAtURL: function also never gets called, Any update on this?

Comment: I am also facing this issue. can anyone get me out from this issue?? Please help me out.
Thanks!!